# How to search a file for each entry in a list and print a new file for each entry

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a file (`list_file`) that is a list of names and another file (`data_file`) that contains hundreds of thousands of lines of text, each beginning with a name in `list_file`. I want to do a search of the `data_file` for all lines that start with each name in `list_file` and export the lines for each name to a new file `*.txt` (where `*` is the name in the list)

I have this

```
grep -f "list_file" data_file > out.txt
```

but this does not separate each line in the list into its own file.

Sample `list_file`:

```
100_fullA
100_fullB
105_fullA
105_fullB
112_fullA
112_fullB
121_fullA
121_fullB
```

Sample `data_file`:

```
100_fullA NGATCATCGACAC
100_fullB NGATCATCGACAC
105_fullA NGATCATCGACAC
105_fullB NGATCATCGACAC
112_fullA NGATCATCGACAC
112_fullB NGATCATCGACAC
121_fullA NGATCATCGACAC
```

Answer (score 1):

You could construct a look-up table (or hash) from `list_file`, for example using an associative array in `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {list[$1]=1; next} $1 in list {print > $1".txt"}' list_file data_file
```

The outputs will go in files `100_fullA.txt`, `100_fullB.txt` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way by constructing the commands on the fly:

```
grep -f list_file data_file | sed -e "s/^\([^ ]*\).*/echo '&' >> \1;/" | sh
```

Comment: care to explain?

Comment: grep gets all lines in data_file which match the patterns stored in list_file. The sed then prepares these lines into a form suitable for bash. For example, a line `100_fullA TCAGGNG` => echo 100_fullA TCAGGNG >> 100_fullA. These generated on the fly lines are the fed to bash to effect the operation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read pointer; do
 filename="$(echo $pointer | cut -d ' ' -f 1)" 
 if grep $filename list_file > /dev/null; then
  echo $pointer >> output/"$filename".txt
 fi
done < data_file
```

Here's a breakdown line-by-line:

- Line 3 is the beginning of the while loop used to loop through
  data_file.
- Line 4 echos the line read in the current iteration. The line is then
  passed to cut, which cuts out the first part of the line useing a
  space as the delimiter. The result is then assigned to a variable
  called "filename".
- Line 5 uses grep to determine whether or not the previously
  determined value exists in list_file. If grep succeeds in finding the
  value (return status 0), the script continues to line 6. If grep does not find anything (return status 1), the script starts the loop over.
- Line 6 echos the entire line to output/"$filename".txt.
- Line 7 closes the if statement.
- Line 8 closes the loop and is where data_file is referenced.

Other important notes:

- The "output/" directory must be created before the script is run, otherwise you'll get an error like "output: no such file or directory". If this is a problem, it can be easily solved by adding "mkdir output" to the beginning of the script.
- You mentioned data_file has hundreds of thousands of lines. Because of this, this script will likely take a long time to complete. If you find yourself querying this file for information often, it would be worth translating the information into MariaDB or similar database.
- If list_file also contains many many entries, the script will take an insanely long time to run, because the grep on line 5 queries the entire list_file for every iteration of the loop. Again, this is a problem that can be solved with the tools available in a SQL database.

Comment: This worked well but looking at the new file it would be great to remove the name string from the beginning of each line.

Comment: This can be easily done with a similar cut command on the $pointer variable, then write the new variable to the file instead of $pointer:

http://pastebin.com/75kvHjn4

Edited to use a PasteBin link instead, since I guess comments can't do code blocks.